# constrained delauncy traingulation opencv on a contour or convexhull

Tags: opencv, constraints, triangulation, delaunay

I want to know the method of doing CDT(constrained delauncy triangulation) using opencv C++ / C api , on a contour or convex hull .

my question is similar to

[C++-ObjC OpenCV Constrained Delaunay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236201/c-objc-opencv-constrained-delaunay)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it applies to your specific problem, but there is a similar question. It seems that the OpenCV Delaunay functions are available but not documented.

[Is there C++ API for Delaunay triangulation in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170564/is-there-c-api-for-delaunay-triangulation-in-opencv)